# In intelliJ, how to move an method to an implementing class of an interface?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ 2016.2.1.

I have a method `foo()` in main class Test:

```
class Test {
   IService iService;

   foo(){...}

}
```

`IService` is an interface, it has one implementing class `ServiceImpl`.
When I put caret on `foo`, and select move, intelliJ only allows me to select `IService`. But I actually want `ServiceImpl` as move destination.

And if I continue the move, intelliJ will put the method implementation inside the interface `IService`. But I want to have an declaration there.

---

**Question**: How do I refactor foo(), to move its method implementation into ServiceImpl, and method declaration in IService?

Comment: I am using Intellij 14 and I don't know of a move command. Why not just cut and paste?

Comment: @NoahHerron What kind of statement is that? Of course it is **always** the better alternative to do refactoring via tooling. The idea is that your IDE exactly knows where a method is called from; and might do updates to other code; or tell you about problem that will come into existing when moving stuff around. In that sense: this is a very legit question.

Comment: @GhostCat did it come off like I was saying this was a bad question? If so my bad. Also there was development long before IDEs. It will make you a better developer to break it until you fix it.

Comment: how is it possible that the IDE moves a method implementation into the Interface ?, interfaces do not contain method implementations

Comment: @OsamaSalama per Java 8, interface can have default method implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you move the method to `IService`, use Refactor | Push Members Down... to move it to `ServiceImpl`.